# Implementing a Number.prototype.loop(callback)

Tags: javascript, prototype

How to pass a reference of an argument, originally passed to a prototype function, on to a callback function which, too, is passed to the same prototype function?

The objective of the implementation is to loop for the value of the `Number` by executing the callback function.

```
Number.prototype.loop = function(index, callback) {
  return Array(this).fill(0).forEach((e, i) => {
    if(callback)
      callback();
  });
};

var num = 3;

num.loop(index, function(){
  console.log(index);
});
```

**Solution**

Apparently, the reference to `index` is supposed to be passed directly to the callback function in order to indicate that the actual index property of the `Array` in the prototype function is to be passed to the callback function.

```
Number.prototype.loop = function(callback) {
  return Array(this).fill(0).forEach((e, i) => {
    if(callback)
      callback(i);
  });
};

var num = 3;

num.loop((index) => {
  console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 errors.

1. Pass the index `i` to `callback` in `Number.prototype.loop` function instead of the caller:

   - `num.loop(index, function(index) {` → `num.loop(function(index) {`
   - `Number.prototype.loop = function(index, callback) {` → `Number.prototype.loop = function(callback) {`
   - `callback();` → `callback(i);`
2. Pass the numerical value of `this` instead of the instance itself to the `Array` constructor:

   - `Array(this)` → `Array(this.valueOf())`

```js
Number.prototype.loop = function(callback) {
  var num = this.valueOf();
  return Array(num).fill(0).forEach((e, i) => {
    if (callback)
      callback(i);
  });
};

var num = 3;

num.loop(function(index) {
  console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend a `Number` native class with a function `loop` as the following. However, it is advised to not extend native as per this [`eslint's rule`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extend-native) described.

```js
Number.prototype.loop = function (callback) {
    [...Array(this.valueOf())].forEach((_, idx) => {
        callback(idx);
    })
};

const num = 30;

num.loop((idx) => {
    console.log(idx);
})
```

Comment: Is there any performance advantage for using [...Array(this.valueOf())] instead of Array(this.valueOf()).fill(0)?

Comment: @WaleedQidan You can take a look at [this](https://jsperf.com/array-num-fill-0-vs-array-num-vs-for-loop) performance comparison by yourself.